# Ошибка при использовании ThreadPoolExecutor на Windows 10

Tags: python, многопоточность

Вот сам код:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import os
import face_recognition
data_base = 'DB_img'


def f(img_path):
    try:
        encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(img_path)[0]
        return encoding

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = []
    for img in os.listdir(data_base):
      lst.append(face_recognition.load_image_file(data_base + '/' + img))

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as p:
        result = p.map(f, lst)
```

При попытке запустить выдает следующую ошибку:

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: На windows нужно, чтобы f подключалась из внешнего файла, если я правильно помню